# ActionsScript 3 Collision

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, collision-detection, collision

[Frog](http://epickris.co.uk/portfolio/frog)

I'm developing a flash game called Frog, at the moment my code for collision between my frog and fly doesn't work as expected. I'd like to have it so it works something similar to the method linked below (last example).

[Collision detection methods, hitTest and hitTestObject alternatives](http://sierakowski.eu/list-of-tips/39-collision-detection-methods-hittest-and-hittestobject-alternatives.html)

Any help would be appreciated.

```
function hitTargetFunction():void {
    for (i = 0; i < insectsMC.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < insectsMC[i].length; j++) {
            if (frogMC.hitTestObject(insectsMC[i][j])) {
                trace('Target: ' + insectsMC[i][j].name);
                score +=  1;
                trace('Score: '+score);
                insectsMC[i][j].x = 0 - insectsMC[i][j].width * 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @SamDeHaan Basically this code adds a 'bounding box' around the object which is a square, however, I don't want 'empty' parts of my movie clip to count as the collision.

Comment: If there's no way around this I think I'll create a small movie clip within the moveiclip and just have it at the end of the frog's tongue and use that instead of the whole frog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a movieclip/sprite inside the frog movieclip will probably be the best thing for you in this situation. PixelPerfectCollision is very awesome and useful(however on larger games, expensive) but the collision would then be with any piece of the frog. You could of course break apart your frog movieclip and just do PixelPerfectCollision on just the tongue. But if this is for coursework I'd stick to just doing hitTest() on a display object of some kind inside the the frog.

Answer (score 2):

Might I suggest trying out the fantastic [Collision Detection Kit](http://code.google.com/p/collisiondetectionkit/)?

I'm sure it will do everything you need and more. It's also AS3 which is what your code sample is written in, so I hope you find it useful.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer since it's the best solution, although I'm doing this for coursework and can't really use that code unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not allowed to use a third-party library for your coursework you should have a look at this excellent tutorial on [pixel-level collision detection with ActionScript 3.0](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/games/pixel-level-collision-detection/).

The general idea is that you create BitmapData copies of your vector graphics and use the hitTest method of that class to check for a collision at a pixel-level.